# aws s3 bucket availability ( health ) check using api

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have implemented **s3 file upload** in a node.js application, sometime the s3 bucket goes down for maintenance or some other reason. I thought about implementing **api that check weather the s3 bucket is healthy ( working fine ) or not** , so that user be aware of the issue. but was unable to find the api endpoint for this.

I did found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867049/how-to-check-if-aws-s3-bucket-available-before-uploading-file-using-outbound-gat) but it didn't help me.

Thanks

Comment: How often does an S3 bucket go down for maintenance? If you’re using redundant storage that should be a non-issue in practice.

Comment: i'm not familiar with the redundant storage ill be using a different s3 bucket to upload if one is down. i know it happens rarely but can't ignore the issue.

Comment: Buckets do not "go down". There might be an extremely rare case where Amazon S3 goes down (very few in a 10-year history), but that would affect _all_ buckets in a region, not just one bucket. It is more likely that there is a network problem between you and AWS.

Answer (score 0):

S3 has 99.999999999% uptime durability, which should really be enough not to worry about. To be safe, include an error check in the SDK upload. If you are seriously worried, then maybe queue up a few re-tries and then inform the user. For larger objects use multipart upload.

Comment: i'm using multipart upload, have implemented the error handling retry too. what i'm asking that is their a way that i can check the status or not [using api]. ( i get that their service is repayable )

Comment: The only other possibility I can think of is to run a synthetics canary from CloudWatch on the bucket endpoint (never tried this, but could be possible). Personally, I think it would be overkill.

Comment: Uptime is separate from durability, and you can see here that S3's uptime SLA is much lower than that: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/ . Health checking is also an important reliability pattern for some scenarios.